# android phone mount desktop partitions via USB port (Reverse USB Tethering in disk level?)

Tags: android, linux-kernel, usb, mount

I am wondering if it's possible to tell the Linux kernel of android phone to mount a desktop partition as part of the phone's file systems, while this phone is connected to the desktop via USB.

Do I have to modify kernel in order to do that, and if so, how hard might it be? I understand that mounting an USB drive from desktop is standard feature for every Linux.However I am not quite sure if USB communication is symmetric enough so that the other way around (mounting desktop disk for a phone can be easily implemented.

In some sense this is similar to Reverse USB Tethering (http://blog.mycila.com/2010/06/reverse-usb-tethering-with-android-22.html). But instead of let phone use host's network connection, I want to let the phone use host's disk.

Anyone has some thoughts on this?

EDIT:

I want to do this because in order to experiment something I need to pretend that my phone has a superfast sdcard (faster than what's available in the market), so I want to simulate it through desktop ramdisk (which is basically disk in memory)

Update:

After a bit searching I found out that with these two products:
A host-to-host usb cable:
[http://www.amazon.com/Plugable-USB-Easy-Transfer-Cable/dp/B005OTPVMY/ref=pd_sim_sbs_pc_1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B005OTPVMY)
And an USB OTG cable:
[http://www.amazon.com/T-Flash-Adapter-Samsung-GT-i9100-GT-N7000/dp/B005FUNYSA](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B005FUNYSA)

I could turn an USB-OTG enabled phone into an USB host, and use whatever USB driver which runs on a computer. I am not sure what speed I will get after those two transformation though? Anyone could comment on that? Or can I somehow combine those two adapters into one "A to OTG cable"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a discussion about this with the linux-usb development people on linux-usb mail list, and got a satisfactory answer. Basically I need to get a PLX net2282 card to turn my desktop into an USB slave, then run USB gadget driver on it.

Details can be found here:
http://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-usb/msg72012.html

Comment: This is a relatively poor recommendation, as it ignores the fact that **stock android does not support mounting USB storage volumes**.  You'd be better off simply establishing a network connection and proxying access over that, possibly treating it as a network file system on the PC end, but requiring handling within app code on the Android side.

Answer (score 0):

The external file system of an Android device can only be an SD Card. So far as I know this is not possible. Android expects its file system to be only on an SD card.

Comment: I don't mind change android or the kernel, I just want to get a sense on how hard it might be,giving the nature of USB communication.

Comment: But what are you trying to achieve by that? You will have to dig very deep into the Android Kernel and still I'm skeptic if this is possible.

Comment: I need to pretend I have a super fast ad card, so I want to simulate it using desktop ramdisk.

Comment: Can you be more specific of your problem?

Comment: So basically I want my phone to mount a partition which can provide really fast IO, and I am trying to use desktop memory for this

Comment: See ideally IO speed depends on the speed of the processor and RAM of your phone or in case if your using an emulator  you will need at least 8GB of RAM to simulate fast IO.

Comment: I think it is limited by USB speed, but hopefully USB is fast enough. I am using real phone, that's why I have this problem. If it's emulator I can simply put system.img in memory. And yes, I have enough ram.

Comment: IO is part of the CPU. The speed of USB 2.0 is good enough. It all depends on the IO unit on your phone's CPU and RAM for caching data.

Comment: I don't know if CPU will be the limiting factor, but I will need to simulate a fast block device in order to answer that.

Comment: And I am not using phone's ram, I plan to use the desktop ram. Phone's internal page cache is not my concern here, I only care about block level access speed.

Comment: Maybe you could elaborate a bit, but I think you didn't get what I am trying to achieve here.....Of course block device effect IO performance

Comment: Maybe you could elaborate a bit, but I think you didn't get what I am trying to achieve here.....Of course block device affect IO performance, which in turn affect other things. So I need to simulate a fast block device here....

Comment: I absolutely understand what you are trying to do. Here you go most of the Android phones use the ARM architecture which uses a RISC processor where the instructions are carried out on the register and not on the memory directly. Registers stay on the processor not on any external file system. This defies the very purpose of your hypothetical IO implementation. Read here for more http://www.arm.com/products/processors/instruction-set-architectures/index.php

Comment: So? I only need to serve bio request fast, like every sdcard manufactor is trying to do.....

Comment: You ain't getting what I'm trying to tell you. The speed is dependent on CPU and nothing else. IO unit is responsible for data transfer no matter how much fast the data transfer speed is supported by the transfer medium it all depends on the processor. Think this way why do some phones support super fast Wifi speeds and other don't inspite of using the same Specification. The answer is the processor speed and RAM.

Comment: Are you suggesting that a faster sdcard is not going to make your phone faster with the same CPU? If so, I urge you to read 2012 FAST paper by NEC lab, where they experimentally show storage matters.

Comment: What you said is true but USB 2.0 offers you a effective throughput up to 35 MB/s. Unless you need more than this the speed limiting doesn't occur. Also what you are now talking is about the caching and other memory concerns, though caching has affect on IO. Intially your problem was about IO speed. That is what I understand.

Comment: See, that is where you get me wrong. I am not talking about phone's memory cache nor do I care about it.

Comment: and all importantly a RISC processor has been designed this way to be less power hungry. You will defeat the very purpose of RISC if you try to mount a desktop file system on it. RISC was never designed to be a processor which can handle desktop file system. Unless you decide to write a kernel for X86 architecture phone what you are trying to achieve is not possible and not advised.

Comment: you are confused how can you use RAM as a disk except for temporary volatile memory?

Comment: You have to try to think from a different point of view or else you will neverget to the other side of the river.

Comment: please read the comment about RISC. Understand why RISC and android have been designed the way they have been. Defeating their purpose will not help you ans also I have only involved myself to make you understand this.