# access Data on PC by Phone via USB

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

Is It possible, to get some data via usb from your pc with an app, or must there be another software on the PC that pushes the needed files to the Phone?

to clarify what i mean:
i have a pc with a MySQL Database which is used and maintained by a programm on the pc. what i need are some informations of this DB, so i want to have a button in my app, which says sth. like "Get it!" and then the app connects to the DB via USB, retrieves all the data needed and then displays it on the screen (for example).

Answer (score 0):

Check this question: [android phone mount desktop partitions via USB port (Reverse USB Tethering in disk level?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12702299/android-phone-mount-desktop-partitions-via-usb-port-reverse-usb-tethering-in-di?rq=1) and read the first answer's link, which seems to get into something similar to what you want, albeit not using xamarin.android